# Definition of an $E$-rudimentary function

Tags: set-theory

For a given set or class $E$, we call $f: V^k \rightarrow V$, where $k < \omega$, $E$-rudimentary, iff it can be generated by the following schemata:

- $f(x_1,\ldots,x_k) = x_i$
- $f(x_1,\ldots,x_k) = x_i \setminus x_j$
- $f(x_1,\ldots,x_k) = \{x_i,x_j\}$
- $f(x_1,\ldots,x_k) = h(g_1(x_1^1, \ldots, x_{k_1}^1), \ldots, g_l(x_1^l, \ldots, x_{k_l}^l))$
- $f(x_1,\ldots,x_k) = \bigcup_{y \in x_1} g(y,x_2, \ldots, x_k)$
- $f(x) = x \cap E$,

where I understand $h,g_i,g$ to be $E$-rudimentary functions.

Now I have some trouble with this "$f(x_1,\ldots,x_k) = h(g_1(x_1^1, \ldots, x_{k_1}^1), \ldots, g_l(x_1^l, \ldots, x_{k_l}^l))$":

Am I right, that the $(x_a^b)_a$ are just elements of $\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\}^{< \omega}$? If not, then what are they?

Comment: @Andres Ok, thank you. That is exactly what I thought the definition means. If you want to post this as an anwser, I can accept it as such.

Comment: Sure. I have moved the comments to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $i=1,\dots,l$, you have a function $n_i:\{1,\dots,k_i\}\to\{1,\dots,k\}$ where $k_i$ is the arity of $g_i$. Given $x_1,\dots,x_k$, you then define 
$$ x^i_m=x_{n_i(m)}. $$  So, for instance, you could have $E$-rud functions $h,g,j$ and define $f$ by $$ f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=h(g(x_1,x_3,x_5),j(x_2,x_2,x_2,x_1)), $$ with the relevant schema asserting that $f$ is also $E$-rudimentary.

In this example, $g_1=g$, $g_2=j$, $k_1=3$, $k_2=4$ and, given $x_1,\dots,x_5$, we have that $x^1_1=x_1$, $x^1_2=x_3$, $x^1_3=x_5$, $x^2_1=x^2_2=x^2_3=x_2$, and $x^2_4=x_1$. Here, $n_1:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,\dots,5\}$ is given by $n_1(1)=1$, $n_1(2)=3$, and $n_1(3)=5$, and $n_2:\{1,\dots,4\}\to\{1,\dots,5\}$ is given by $n_2(1)=n_2(2)=n_2(3)=2$, and $n_2(4)=1$.